# Can not figure out why org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Currently, I am developing an application using the Spring framework and Maven in NetBeans IDE.
When I compile by enabling testing, I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:276)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:278)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [testingContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1045)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:824)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
at org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.addTransformer(InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.java:88)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.addTransformer(SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.java:82)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:348)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
... 46 more
```

I cannot figure out why this error happens and how to fix it.

My testingContext.xml is as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="DataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
      p:url="${jdbc.url}"
      p:username="${jdbc.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}"
      />

<bean id="loadTimeWeaver" class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter"
    p:showSql="true"
    p:databasePlatform="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="DataSource"
    p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaVendorAdapter"
    p:persistenceXmlLocation="test-persistence.xml"
/>

<!-- Transaction manager for a single JPA EntityManagerFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
<bean id="transactionManager" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:dataSource-ref="DataSource" 
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

<!-- checks for annotated configured beans -->
<context:annotation-config/>  

<!-- Scan for Repository/Service annotations -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.insure.riskmanage.dao" />

<!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

In my program, I have the EntityManager defined already:

```
package com.insure.riskmanage.dao;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public class GenericFile<T, ID> {
final protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "insurePU")
protected EntityManager em;

final private Class<T> type;

public GenericFile(Class<T> type1) {
    this.type = type1;
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void create(T obj) {
    em.persist(obj);
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public T read(ID id) {
    return (T) em.find(type, id);
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public T update(T obj) {
    obj = em.merge(obj);
    return obj;
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void delete(T obj) {
    // associate object with persistence context
    obj = em.merge(obj);
    em.remove(obj);               
}
}
```

What else should I look into? Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: The error says: *java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.*. So, open the documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/). Then hit Ctrl-F to search in the documentation, search for "InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver", and there you go: the instructions on how to start Java with that InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.

Answer (score 2):

One of the nested exceptions states:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.

Judging from the Javadoc of [`InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/instrument/classloading/InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.html), you need to start the JVM with a special agent that's shipped with Spring.

```
-javaagent:path/to/org.springframework.instrument.jar
```

Comment: I hate to inform you that I have no idea how to do that. I am using NetBeans IDE 8.2 and didn't touch any JVM starting at all.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone that have responded to my question.
At last I found out the reason why I got this error.
It is in my pom.xml file. There is one tag with additonal > character.
Instead of , there is an additional character > like the following:

```
  <artifactId>>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
```

Somehow, it is not detected, but just ignore the rest of the pom.xml file, I think.